# pandas apply() function without having to return a value? / quick looping through df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large (~145000 rows) Database of recipes I'm working on. I have a column 'parsed_ingredients' which looks like this(multiple dicts per row):

```
[{'orig_name': '1,00 kg Kalbsbraten ',
  'orig_amount': '1.00',
  'orig_unit': 'kg',
  'amount': 0.25,
  'unit': 'g',
  'splitted_ingredient': 'Kalbsbraten',
  'splitted_slized_ingredient': 'Kalbsbraten',
  'further_specification': '',
  'alternatives': '',
  'matched_ingredient_id': 'U030100',
  'matched_ingredient_st': 'Kalb Hackfleisch roh',
  'calorie': 148,
  'protein': 19.726,
  'carb': 0.0,
  'fat': 7.713},
 {'orig_name': '1,00  Zwiebel(n) ',
  'orig_amount': '1.00',
  'orig_unit': 'Anzahl',
  'amount': 9.0,
  'unit': 'g',
  'splitted_ingredient': 'Zwiebel(n)',
  ...
]
```

Basically, I'm trying to prepare my df for a item- and user-based (content-based) recommender system, so I am trying to create a matrix with a column for every ingredient contained in a recipe.

I've tried the following but had the problem that it is simply extremely slow with such a large number of rows:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    extracted_ingredient = ""
    for ingredient in row["parsed_ingredients"]:
        extracted_ingredient = ingredient["matched_ingredient_st"]
        if not extracted_ingredient == "None":
            df.loc[index, extracted_ingredient] = 1
```

So I tried writing a function to use with apply as I read it computes a lot faster, but then realized that apply always wants me to return something to save in the DF (otherwise I get 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable':

```
def ingredient_extraction(content, dataframe=df):
    for newrow in content:
        for entry in newrow:
            if not entry["matched_ingredient_st"] == "None":
                df[entry["matched_ingredient_st"]] = 1

df.apply(ingredient_extraction(df["parsed_ingredients"], df), axis=1)
```

Is there any way I can make pandas apply this function to my df regardless? Or is there a better way to speed up the operation done in iterrows?

Comment: Have you tried itertuples? It's a lot faster than iterrows

Comment: can you post one 2 rows with the nested dicts in full? or just one? if the dict is massive just post a subset of it

Answer (score 0):

First you can generate all values to lists of dictionaries and then pass to `DataFrame` constructor, last join to original:

```
L = [[{'matched_ingredient_id': 'U030100',
  'matched_ingredient_st': 'Kalb',
},
 {  'matched_ingredient_id': 'U030100',
  'matched_ingredient_st': 'Ka',
  'splitted_ingredient': 'Zwiebel(n)'}],[
  {'matched_ingredient_id': 'U030100',
  'matched_ingredient_st': 'roh',
},
 {  'matched_ingredient_id': 'U030100',
  'matched_ingredient_st': 'K',
  'splitted_ingredient': 'Zwiebel'}
]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'parsed_ingredients':L})
```

---

```
L = [{y['matched_ingredient_st']:1 for y in x if not y["matched_ingredient_st"] == "None"}
      for x in df['parsed_ingredients']]


df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
   Kalb  Ka  roh  K
0     1   1    0  0
1     0   0    1  1

df = df.join(df1)
print(df)
                                  parsed_ingredients  Kalb  Ka  roh  K
0  [{'matched_ingredient_id': 'U030100', 'matched...     1   1    0  0
1  [{'matched_ingredient_id': 'U030100', 'matched...     0   0    1  1
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I'll give it a try! Hope you and your family stay healthy!

Answer (score 0):

Just a rough outline of an idea.

Say you have a DataFrame like so:

```
recipe_id | parsed_ingredients
------------------------------
 1        | [{...}, {...}, ...]
 2        | [{...}, {...}, ...]
 3        | [{...}, {...}, ...]
```

Using the `explode` method, expand the DataFrame to show one ingredient dictionary per row.

```
df = df.explode('parsed_ingredients')
df.head()

recipe_id | parsed_ingredients
------------------------------
 1        | {...}
 1        | {...}
     ...
 2        | {...}
 2        | {...}
     ...
 3        | {...}
 3        | {...}
     ...
```

Now extract the `matched_ingredient_st` from each of the dictionaries

```
df['matched_ingredient_st'] = df['parsed_ingredients'].apply(lambda x: x['matched_ingredient_st'])
df['match'] = 1 # Added for the next step
df.head()

recipe_id | parsed_ingredients | matched_ingredient_st | match
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1        | {...}              | ingredient_a          | 1
 1        | {...}              | ingredient_b          | 1
     ...
 2        | {...}              | ingredient_b          | 1
 2        | {...}              | ingredient_d          | 1
     ...
 3        | {...}              | ingredient_c          | 1
 3        | {...}              | ingredient_d          | 1
     ...
```

Now you can use the built in pivot method to reduce the DataFrame back into a similar format at the original dataset

```
df = df.pivot(index='recipe_id ', columns='matched_ingredient_st ', values='match')
df.head()

   | ingredient_a | ingredient_b | ingredient_c | ingredient_d 
---------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |       1      |       1      |       0      |       0      |
 2 |       0      |       1      |       0      |       1      |
 3 |       0      |       0      |       1      |       1      |
```

Haven't actually ran this in Python, but there logic and the methods are there.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll jump in and give this approach a try! Hope you and your family stay healthy!